# How to overwrite mat-slide-toggle/ overwrite Css in components

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, angular-material, less

I have a component which is Sample1.html.component which contains mat slide toogle, I've added a scss but it is not taking effect , is this because of the default of angular material? Thanks.

If it is toggled and checked the color of it should be #56ff00 like on the scss below.

## Angular toogle

```
<mat-slide-toggle #relayToggle  [checked]="hasBeenChecked" labelPosition="before" (change)="relayChanged($event)">
      Toggle
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

## scss

```
:host {
  @include full-width();

  .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked {

    & .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
      background-color: #56ff00 !important;
    }

    & .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
      background-color: #56ff008a !important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: In which scss file did you write your code? is this scss code scoped to your component? You need to create a `theme.scss` (or use the one that's already created) and put all material overwrites in a global scss file.  https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: yeah2 , it is scope on my component

Comment: Then it can't work because mat-slide is not your component. You need to use theme file for these overwrites.

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I've added  styleUrls     : ['./sample1.component.scss'], in my Component

Answer (score 0):

You have a `main.scss` or something similar as your root scss file in your root folder.

Inside this `main.scss` (or whatever it's called in your project) you can [include your themes](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). Just add something like

```
// Theme customization
@import 'theme/theme';
```

in this file.

Then in your `theme` folder create a `_theme.scss` file and add this code:

```
.mat-slide-toggle {
  border-top-color: pink;
}
```

to have a pink top border for your `.mat-slide-toggle`